# SSL Chat Error Client Certificate and TLSv1.2 can't be recognized

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, client-certificates

I have problem with my SSL Chat application in Java with Eclipse in Ubuntu. I have the code like this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.*;

public class SSLSocketClient {


    private static String host;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cipher = null;
        String portNo;
        String chatType;
        String mykeystoreValue;
        int port = 0;
        boolean mykeystore = false;
        boolean chat = false;

        if (args.length == 5) {

            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

                if (args[i].equals("-host")) {
                    host = args[++i];
                    continue;
                }
                if (args[i].equals("-port")) {
                    portNo = args[++i];
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portNo);
                    continue;
                }
                if (args[i].equals("-cipher")) {
                    cipher = args[++i];
                    continue;
                }
                if (args[i].equals("-chat")) {
                    chat = true;
                    continue;
                }

                if (args[i].equals("-mykeystore")) {
                    mykeystore = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Please check again parameter!");
        }

        if (mykeystore) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "mykeystore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "kosuke");
        }

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(null, null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) sc.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket mysslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);

            if (cipher != null) {
                String[] cipherarray = { cipher };
                mysslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherarray);
            }

            mysslsocket.startHandshake();
            mysslsocket.close();

            if (chat){



            }



        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

And my argument in the terminal like this

```
java SSLSocketClient -host localhost -port 11111 -mykeystore
```

and the result in the terminal:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.2 SSLContext not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:142)
    at SSLSocketClient.SSLClient(SSLSocketClient.java:33)
    at SSLSocketClient.main(SSLSocketClient.java:106)
```

and the result in the server terminal:

```
   Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
ACCEPT
SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
read from 0x147cb40 [0x14868a0] (11 bytes => 11 (0xB))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 dd 01 00 00-d9 03 03                  ...........
read from 0x147cb40 [0x14868ae] (215 bytes => 215 (0xD7))
0000 - 52 ac 5e a8 58 2b 7b 25-63 37 01 f9 d8 83 0c 6c   R.^.X+{%c7.....l
0010 - 97 bc 7b c2 77 6d e8 e4-fc a1 49 28 d7 f2 b7 bd   ..{.wm....I(....
0020 - 00 00 54 c0 24 c0 28 00-3d c0 26 c0 2a 00 6b 00   ..T.$.(.=.&.*.k.
0030 - 6a c0 0a c0 14 00 35 c0-05 c0 0f 00 39 00 38 c0   j.....5.....9.8.
0040 - 23 c0 27 00 3c c0 25 c0-29 00 67 00 40 c0 09 c0   #.'.<.%.).g.@...
0050 - 13 00 2f c0 04 c0 0e 00-33 00 32 c0 07 c0 11 00   ../.....3.2.....
0060 - 05 c0 02 c0 0c c0 08 c0-12 00 0a c0 03 c0 0d 00   ................
0070 - 16 00 13 00 04 00 ff 01-00 00 5c 00 0a 00 34 00   ..........\...4.
0080 - 32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00-13 00 15 00 06 00 07 00   2...............
0090 - 09 00 0a 00 18 00 0b 00-0c 00 19 00 0d 00 0e 00   ................
00a0 - 0f 00 10 00 11 00 02 00-12 00 04 00 05 00 14 00   ................
00b0 - 08 00 16 00 0b 00 02 01-00 00 0d 00 1a 00 18 06   ................
00c0 - 03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04-03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02   ................
00d0 - 03 02 01 02 02 01 01                              .......
<<< TLS 1.2  [length 00dd]
    01 00 00 d9 03 03 52 ac 5e a8 58 2b 7b 25 63 37
    01 f9 d8 83 0c 6c 97 bc 7b c2 77 6d e8 e4 fc a1
    49 28 d7 f2 b7 bd 00 00 54 c0 24 c0 28 00 3d c0
    26 c0 2a 00 6b 00 6a c0 0a c0 14 00 35 c0 05 c0
    0f 00 39 00 38 c0 23 c0 27 00 3c c0 25 c0 29 00
    67 00 40 c0 09 c0 13 00 2f c0 04 c0 0e 00 33 00
    32 c0 07 c0 11 00 05 c0 02 c0 0c c0 08 c0 12 00
    0a c0 03 c0 0d 00 16 00 13 00 04 00 ff 01 00 00
    5c 00 0a 00 34 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00
    15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00 0a 00 18 00 0b 00 0c 00
    19 00 0d 00 0e 00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00
    04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00 0b 00 02 01 00 00
    0d 00 1a 00 18 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04
    01 03 03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02 02 01 01
SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client hello A
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 0059]
    02 00 00 55 03 03 52 ac 5e a8 54 bc 77 0d 45 65
    87 6a c2 5a bc dd d1 cd d5 25 d7 27 e1 ed a1 20
    e9 62 55 c6 29 a3 20 d4 87 99 21 e8 42 6e ad f0
    d1 b0 f2 1a c6 dc 66 31 0c c6 ec 54 1d cd 42 40
    ae 10 e5 64 35 ca 0e c0 28 00 00 0d ff 01 00 01
    00 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02
write to 0x147cb40 [0x14902c0] (94 bytes => 94 (0x5E))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 59 02 00 00-55 03 03 52 ac 5e a8 54   ....Y...U..R.^.T
0010 - bc 77 0d 45 65 87 6a c2-5a bc dd d1 cd d5 25 d7   .w.Ee.j.Z.....%.
0020 - 27 e1 ed a1 20 e9 62 55-c6 29 a3 20 d4 87 99 21   '... .bU.). ...!
0030 - e8 42 6e ad f0 d1 b0 f2-1a c6 dc 66 31 0c c6 ec   .Bn........f1...
0040 - 54 1d cd 42 40 ae 10 e5-64 35 ca 0e c0 28 00 00   T..B@...d5...(..
0050 - 0d ff 01 00 01 00 00 0b-00 04 03 00 01 02         ..............
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 0774]
    0b 00 07 70 00 07 6d 00 03 3f 30 82 03 3b 30 82
    02 23 a0 03 02 01 02 02 01 01 30 0d 06 09 2a 86
    48 86 f7 0d 01 01 05 05 00 30 69 31 0b 30 09 06
    03 55 04 06 13 02 44 45 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04
    08 13 03 4e 52 57 31 0e 30 0c 06 03 55 04 07 13
    05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 11 30 0f 06 03 55 04 0a 13
    08 46 48 20 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55
    04 0b 13 03 4c 41 62 31 1b 30 19 06 03 55 04 03
    13 12 54 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 6e 74 65 72 20 49
    68 73 61 6e 30 1e 17 0d 31 33 31 32 30 39 31 35
    31 34 34 37 5a 17 0d 31 34 31 32 30 39 31 35 31
    34 34 37 5a 30 60 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13
    02 44 45 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 08 13 03 4e 52
    57 31 0e 30 0c 06 03 55 04 07 13 05 4b 6f 65 6c
    6e 31 11 30 0f 06 03 55 04 0a 13 08 46 48 20 4b
    6f 65 6c 6e 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 0b 13 03 4c
    61 62 31 12 30 10 06 03 55 04 03 13 09 6c 6f 63
    61 6c 68 6f 73 74 30 81 9f 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48
    86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8d 00 30 81 89 02
    81 81 00 97 66 49 30 d3 80 c0 ff ab 12 f4 39 43
    69 35 b2 a2 c4 56 02 f3 7e 24 7c 42 b8 fd 16 d7
    30 d2 bc d5 50 71 f6 97 51 d6 f6 4d 8e c1 d0 f3
    99 c5 61 2c 04 36 d8 d1 98 9b df 2e 65 03 29 6b
    1f 91 77 80 62 3c eb a1 58 14 58 4b 11 07 db e0
    10 27 29 41 fd 53 2d c4 e7 16 5b 30 91 5d 42 67
    f0 ee 6f 04 34 28 9f c0 97 93 5d 17 47 7c 18 72
    84 7b 14 77 94 c3 66 46 2f a0 23 62 26 61 87 58
    6f eb 69 02 03 01 00 01 a3 7b 30 79 30 09 06 03
    55 1d 13 04 02 30 00 30 2c 06 09 60 86 48 01 86
    f8 42 01 0d 04 1f 16 1d 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 4c 20
    47 65 6e 65 72 61 74 65 64 20 43 65 72 74 69 66
    69 63 61 74 65 30 1d 06 03 55 1d 0e 04 16 04 14
    55 cc 05 ed 34 6f 6f fc 63 31 23 60 bb 67 f8 7f
    7e fa 10 c1 30 1f 06 03 55 1d 23 04 18 30 16 80
    14 f3 cb 73 5e a5 59 07 02 1a eb 7e b8 23 0f f3
    f5 8a 95 e3 a6 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01
    01 05 05 00 03 82 01 01 00 0b 8d 6a 33 fe 23 50
    87 de 01 53 f2 1a ab 76 cf d9 ae fc 1f d8 b5 d4
    e4 2f 79 4f 6b b1 cc 77 65 04 7b b0 da c7 57 e3
    8c 6a f6 fe 3d ac 02 4d 95 e4 ab 88 c0 b0 10 26
    32 0d 47 7f d7 a6 7d 63 39 ab 4b ca c7 b9 de 83
    45 77 03 01 2f 49 78 e8 08 0a 21 ec 80 c2 d0 43
    b0 dc 5e c3 4f 0d 1b 04 77 cb 5d 5e f2 a4 03 56
    8c 3f c1 06 ee 94 cd 1d 8f 89 af b1 62 63 9f ec
    de 7d 09 b1 ce b3 b7 b0 48 54 a4 1a da 6c 04 fc
    b7 23 51 ec 4d 24 78 15 89 9d 24 a2 80 8e 0b 45
    3b f5 87 d5 18 d9 9f b3 d1 23 a3 99 50 4c 7b 77
    b1 fa f0 7b 67 8d 71 dc 17 c2 90 fd ec a8 b4 20
    d4 07 d2 d6 c8 cc 1f 64 28 42 e3 d0 91 ef 02 4e
    21 48 b1 fe e5 09 26 87 08 16 33 56 a4 78 27 fd
    5a b2 69 b8 f5 c5 e3 a1 8f 70 00 b8 02 3c 3c 86
    78 1b 2d b1 59 7a ad 0b 74 07 a0 6c a8 5e e8 f2
    95 c9 9a b8 86 bd 8a b2 4c 00 04 28 30 82 04 24
    30 82 03 0c a0 03 02 01 02 02 09 00 f1 d1 e7 03
    e4 b3 7c 32 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01
    05 05 00 30 69 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02
    44 45 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 08 13 03 4e 52 57
    31 0e 30 0c 06 03 55 04 07 13 05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e
    31 11 30 0f 06 03 55 04 0a 13 08 46 48 20 4b 6f
    65 6c 6e 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 0b 13 03 4c 41
    62 31 1b 30 19 06 03 55 04 03 13 12 54 72 75 73
    74 20 43 65 6e 74 65 72 20 49 68 73 61 6e 30 1e
    17 0d 31 33 31 32 30 39 31 35 31 30 35 30 5a 17
    0d 31 36 30 39 30 34 31 35 31 30 35 30 5a 30 69
    31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 44 45 31 0c 30
    0a 06 03 55 04 08 13 03 4e 52 57 31 0e 30 0c 06
    03 55 04 07 13 05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 11 30 0f 06
    03 55 04 0a 13 08 46 48 20 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 0c
    30 0a 06 03 55 04 0b 13 03 4c 41 62 31 1b 30 19
    06 03 55 04 03 13 12 54 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 6e
    74 65 72 20 49 68 73 61 6e 30 82 01 22 30 0d 06
    09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0f
    00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 bf 55 24 8f e0 e3
    45 e1 4f 76 12 d3 f8 9d 8a 59 3d a2 30 c2 59 7e
    fc 97 8f d8 2c b1 7e 90 08 f8 ce 72 65 b8 34 65
    42 e2 86 a3 e4 a7 63 1d 45 eb 72 61 63 74 a6 e0
    f1 89 73 20 7b 01 e1 1d be 4a 30 0d 83 0d ef 04
    2a db c3 f6 ba 39 ce d1 9d 01 c2 38 bc 5c a1 f8
    55 05 28 a7 86 50 ac ab 83 19 0b 65 74 9b 3f 66
    31 2e a0 cd 84 92 a2 4d 01 cd 98 e8 28 20 6d c2
    3b 46 70 27 10 47 26 ef 96 1e 6f 36 d4 c5 d7 24
    f2 22 0d 23 01 bc f8 98 f8 52 c4 a5 dc e3 a1 77
    de 7d 04 9a cb 18 f8 db fe b2 83 b9 6a ec 32 85
    f2 5e 54 81 ba 2a 34 8c 68 28 da d0 3c 9e b5 54
    89 ba de 4e 82 c0 c1 e9 a2 f7 c9 55 f9 0d 1b a2
    e6 f0 91 c1 35 ba ab bf 3e 9e 82 8e 73 76 18 cf
    fb bc 35 42 97 35 0e 7f 3d f2 ae 7c 6a 76 71 0b
    8a 43 86 7d 7a 4b b2 5e 26 1f b4 06 66 3a 2b 3a
    6b 93 f5 20 34 c9 9e 13 83 e1 02 03 01 00 01 a3
    81 ce 30 81 cb 30 1d 06 03 55 1d 0e 04 16 04 14
    f3 cb 73 5e a5 59 07 02 1a eb 7e b8 23 0f f3 f5
    8a 95 e3 a6 30 81 9b 06 03 55 1d 23 04 81 93 30
    81 90 80 14 f3 cb 73 5e a5 59 07 02 1a eb 7e b8
    23 0f f3 f5 8a 95 e3 a6 a1 6d a4 6b 30 69 31 0b
    30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 44 45 31 0c 30 0a 06
    03 55 04 08 13 03 4e 52 57 31 0e 30 0c 06 03 55
    04 07 13 05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 11 30 0f 06 03 55
    04 0a 13 08 46 48 20 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 0c 30 0a
    06 03 55 04 0b 13 03 4c 41 62 31 1b 30 19 06 03
    55 04 03 13 12 54 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 6e 74 65
    72 20 49 68 73 61 6e 82 09 00 f1 d1 e7 03 e4 b3
    7c 32 30 0c 06 03 55 1d 13 04 05 30 03 01 01 ff
    30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 05 05 00 03
    82 01 01 00 b7 df 61 14 5d 57 17 3c c0 2c fe 37
    df c2 24 ce ea 61 6b 84 d2 fa f3 6a cd 79 f1 71
    08 f6 8c bf ed d6 60 38 d2 35 62 23 5b 3f 9e 23
    32 61 b4 fb a3 3d f5 df 14 ca 59 50 37 fc d3 0c
    bb 13 b2 0d 1c 1f b4 9b 6b 6f b2 b6 9d c9 d3 d6
    a4 f1 7e 07 aa 52 47 39 a9 7a a3 b4 1c ba 88 c2
    f6 27 e8 b4 49 55 62 7c 92 23 6b 4b 70 a7 52 db
    9e 3a aa e6 d3 d7 53 0f f4 e0 60 ae ee f9 ce 69
    23 d0 66 c6 a5 9e 2f 79 ae fd e2 62 41 bf c8 66
    15 40 6e 1a 81 52 4e 50 1d 57 b9 b9 03 dc 26 bf
    04 47 94 30 26 38 72 e8 6d 50 eb 87 ca 31 55 1e
    dc 1e dc 11 ad 19 af 0e 83 18 1c b5 5d 92 d4 2d
    52 e9 9a 04 95 f4 c7 d6 fc 15 8f 37 47 eb 8d 70
    b6 3b f2 36 cb 04 08 f7 fb 31 fc 3a c9 e6 d6 4c
    57 b9 32 7c 8d bf 7e 92 7c f1 95 1c 09 22 f9 14
    a1 f5 e3 71 d2 22 38 72 e4 2d 0d 77 a0 11 fa 9c
    fa 20 0b 97
write to 0x147cb40 [0x14902c0] (1913 bytes => 1913 (0x779))
0000 - 16 03 03 07 74 0b 00 07-70 00 07 6d 00 03 3f 30   ....t...p..m..?0
0010 - 82 03 3b 30 82 02 23 a0-03 02 01 02 02 01 01 30   ..;0..#........0
0020 - 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7-0d 01 01 05 05 00 30 69   ...*.H........0i
0030 - 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04-06 13 02 44 45 31 0c 30   1.0...U....DE1.0
0040 - 0a 06 03 55 04 08 13 03-4e 52 57 31 0e 30 0c 06   ...U....NRW1.0..
0050 - 03 55 04 07 13 05 4b 6f-65 6c 6e 31 11 30 0f 06   .U....Koeln1.0..
0060 - 03 55 04 0a 13 08 46 48-20 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 0c   .U....FH Koeln1.
0070 - 30 0a 06 03 55 04 0b 13-03 4c 41 62 31 1b 30 19   0...U....LAb1.0.
0080 - 06 03 55 04 03 13 12 54-72 75 73 74 20 43 65 6e   ..U....Trust Cen
0090 - 74 65 72 20 49 68 73 61-6e 30 1e 17 0d 31 33 31   ter Ihsan0...131
00a0 - 32 30 39 31 35 31 34 34-37 5a 17 0d 31 34 31 32   209151447Z..1412
00b0 - 30 39 31 35 31 34 34 37-5a 30 60 31 0b 30 09 06   09151447Z0`1.0..
00c0 - 03 55 04 06 13 02 44 45-31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04   .U....DE1.0...U.
00d0 - 08 13 03 4e 52 57 31 0e-30 0c 06 03 55 04 07 13   ...NRW1.0...U...
00e0 - 05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 11-30 0f 06 03 55 04 0a 13   .Koeln1.0...U...
00f0 - 08 46 48 20 4b 6f 65 6c-6e 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55   .FH Koeln1.0...U
0100 - 04 0b 13 03 4c 61 62 31-12 30 10 06 03 55 04 03   ....Lab1.0...U..
0110 - 13 09 6c 6f 63 61 6c 68-6f 73 74 30 81 9f 30 0d   ..localhost0..0.
0120 - 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d-01 01 01 05 00 03 81 8d   ..*.H...........
0130 - 00 30 81 89 02 81 81 00-97 66 49 30 d3 80 c0 ff   .0.......fI0....
0140 - ab 12 f4 39 43 69 35 b2-a2 c4 56 02 f3 7e 24 7c   ...9Ci5...V..~$|
0150 - 42 b8 fd 16 d7 30 d2 bc-d5 50 71 f6 97 51 d6 f6   B....0...Pq..Q..
0160 - 4d 8e c1 d0 f3 99 c5 61-2c 04 36 d8 d1 98 9b df   M......a,.6.....
0170 - 2e 65 03 29 6b 1f 91 77-80 62 3c eb a1 58 14 58   .e.)k..w.b<..X.X
0180 - 4b 11 07 db e0 10 27 29-41 fd 53 2d c4 e7 16 5b   K.....')A.S-...[
0190 - 30 91 5d 42 67 f0 ee 6f-04 34 28 9f c0 97 93 5d   0.]Bg..o.4(....]
01a0 - 17 47 7c 18 72 84 7b 14-77 94 c3 66 46 2f a0 23   .G|.r.{.w..fF/.#
01b0 - 62 26 61 87 58 6f eb 69-02 03 01 00 01 a3 7b 30   b&a.Xo.i......{0
01c0 - 79 30 09 06 03 55 1d 13-04 02 30 00 30 2c 06 09   y0...U....0.0,..
01d0 - 60 86 48 01 86 f8 42 01-0d 04 1f 16 1d 4f 70 65   `.H...B......Ope
01e0 - 6e 53 53 4c 20 47 65 6e-65 72 61 74 65 64 20 43   nSSL Generated C
01f0 - 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61-74 65 30 1d 06 03 55 1d   ertificate0...U.
0200 - 0e 04 16 04 14 55 cc 05-ed 34 6f 6f fc 63 31 23   .....U...4oo.c1#
0210 - 60 bb 67 f8 7f 7e fa 10-c1 30 1f 06 03 55 1d 23   `.g..~...0...U.#
0220 - 04 18 30 16 80 14 f3 cb-73 5e a5 59 07 02 1a eb   ..0.....s^.Y....
0230 - 7e b8 23 0f f3 f5 8a 95-e3 a6 30 0d 06 09 2a 86   ~.#.......0...*.
0240 - 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 05 05-00 03 82 01 01 00 0b 8d   H...............
0250 - 6a 33 fe 23 50 87 de 01-53 f2 1a ab 76 cf d9 ae   j3.#P...S...v...
0260 - fc 1f d8 b5 d4 e4 2f 79-4f 6b b1 cc 77 65 04 7b   ....../yOk..we.{
0270 - b0 da c7 57 e3 8c 6a f6-fe 3d ac 02 4d 95 e4 ab   ...W..j..=..M...
0280 - 88 c0 b0 10 26 32 0d 47-7f d7 a6 7d 63 39 ab 4b   ....&2.G...}c9.K
0290 - ca c7 b9 de 83 45 77 03-01 2f 49 78 e8 08 0a 21   .....Ew../Ix...!
02a0 - ec 80 c2 d0 43 b0 dc 5e-c3 4f 0d 1b 04 77 cb 5d   ....C..^.O...w.]
02b0 - 5e f2 a4 03 56 8c 3f c1-06 ee 94 cd 1d 8f 89 af   ^...V.?.........
02c0 - b1 62 63 9f ec de 7d 09-b1 ce b3 b7 b0 48 54 a4   .bc...}......HT.
02d0 - 1a da 6c 04 fc b7 23 51-ec 4d 24 78 15 89 9d 24   ..l...#Q.M$x...$
02e0 - a2 80 8e 0b 45 3b f5 87-d5 18 d9 9f b3 d1 23 a3   ....E;........#.
02f0 - 99 50 4c 7b 77 b1 fa f0-7b 67 8d 71 dc 17 c2 90   .PL{w...{g.q....
0300 - fd ec a8 b4 20 d4 07 d2-d6 c8 cc 1f 64 28 42 e3   .... .......d(B.
0310 - d0 91 ef 02 4e 21 48 b1-fe e5 09 26 87 08 16 33   ....N!H....&...3
0320 - 56 a4 78 27 fd 5a b2 69-b8 f5 c5 e3 a1 8f 70 00   V.x'.Z.i......p.
0330 - b8 02 3c 3c 86 78 1b 2d-b1 59 7a ad 0b 74 07 a0   ..<<.x.-.Yz..t..
0340 - 6c a8 5e e8 f2 95 c9 9a-b8 86 bd 8a b2 4c 00 04   l.^..........L..
0350 - 28 30 82 04 24 30 82 03-0c a0 03 02 01 02 02 09   (0..$0..........
0360 - 00 f1 d1 e7 03 e4 b3 7c-32 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48   .......|20...*.H
0370 - 86 f7 0d 01 01 05 05 00-30 69 31 0b 30 09 06 03   ........0i1.0...
0380 - 55 04 06 13 02 44 45 31-0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 08   U....DE1.0...U..
0390 - 13 03 4e 52 57 31 0e 30-0c 06 03 55 04 07 13 05   ..NRW1.0...U....
03a0 - 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 11 30-0f 06 03 55 04 0a 13 08   Koeln1.0...U....
03b0 - 46 48 20 4b 6f 65 6c 6e-31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04   FH Koeln1.0...U.
03c0 - 0b 13 03 4c 41 62 31 1b-30 19 06 03 55 04 03 13   ...LAb1.0...U...
03d0 - 12 54 72 75 73 74 20 43-65 6e 74 65 72 20 49 68   .Trust Center Ih
03e0 - 73 61 6e 30 1e 17 0d 31-33 31 32 30 39 31 35 31   san0...131209151
03f0 - 30 35 30 5a 17 0d 31 36-30 39 30 34 31 35 31 30   050Z..1609041510
0400 - 35 30 5a 30 69 31 0b 30-09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02   50Z0i1.0...U....
0410 - 44 45 31 0c 30 0a 06 03-55 04 08 13 03 4e 52 57   DE1.0...U....NRW
0420 - 31 0e 30 0c 06 03 55 04-07 13 05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e   1.0...U....Koeln
0430 - 31 11 30 0f 06 03 55 04-0a 13 08 46 48 20 4b 6f   1.0...U....FH Ko
0440 - 65 6c 6e 31 0c 30 0a 06-03 55 04 0b 13 03 4c 41   eln1.0...U....LA
0450 - 62 31 1b 30 19 06 03 55-04 03 13 12 54 72 75 73   b1.0...U....Trus
0460 - 74 20 43 65 6e 74 65 72-20 49 68 73 61 6e 30 82   t Center Ihsan0.
0470 - 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86-48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05   ."0...*.H.......
0480 - 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82-01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 bf   ......0.........
0490 - 55 24 8f e0 e3 45 e1 4f-76 12 d3 f8 9d 8a 59 3d   U$...E.Ov.....Y=
04a0 - a2 30 c2 59 7e fc 97 8f-d8 2c b1 7e 90 08 f8 ce   .0.Y~....,.~....
04b0 - 72 65 b8 34 65 42 e2 86-a3 e4 a7 63 1d 45 eb 72   re.4eB.....c.E.r
04c0 - 61 63 74 a6 e0 f1 89 73-20 7b 01 e1 1d be 4a 30   act....s {....J0
04d0 - 0d 83 0d ef 04 2a db c3-f6 ba 39 ce d1 9d 01 c2   .....*....9.....
04e0 - 38 bc 5c a1 f8 55 05 28-a7 86 50 ac ab 83 19 0b   8.\..U.(..P.....
04f0 - 65 74 9b 3f 66 31 2e a0-cd 84 92 a2 4d 01 cd 98   et.?f1......M...
0500 - e8 28 20 6d c2 3b 46 70-27 10 47 26 ef 96 1e 6f   .( m.;Fp'.G&...o
0510 - 36 d4 c5 d7 24 f2 22 0d-23 01 bc f8 98 f8 52 c4   6...$.".#.....R.
0520 - a5 dc e3 a1 77 de 7d 04-9a cb 18 f8 db fe b2 83   ....w.}.........
0530 - b9 6a ec 32 85 f2 5e 54-81 ba 2a 34 8c 68 28 da   .j.2..^T..*4.h(.
0540 - d0 3c 9e b5 54 89 ba de-4e 82 c0 c1 e9 a2 f7 c9   .<..T...N.......
0550 - 55 f9 0d 1b a2 e6 f0 91-c1 35 ba ab bf 3e 9e 82   U........5...>..
0560 - 8e 73 76 18 cf fb bc 35-42 97 35 0e 7f 3d f2 ae   .sv....5B.5..=..
0570 - 7c 6a 76 71 0b 8a 43 86-7d 7a 4b b2 5e 26 1f b4   |jvq..C.}zK.^&..
0580 - 06 66 3a 2b 3a 6b 93 f5-20 34 c9 9e 13 83 e1 02   .f:+:k.. 4......
0590 - 03 01 00 01 a3 81 ce 30-81 cb 30 1d 06 03 55 1d   .......0..0...U.
05a0 - 0e 04 16 04 14 f3 cb 73-5e a5 59 07 02 1a eb 7e   .......s^.Y....~
05b0 - b8 23 0f f3 f5 8a 95 e3-a6 30 81 9b 06 03 55 1d   .#.......0....U.
05c0 - 23 04 81 93 30 81 90 80-14 f3 cb 73 5e a5 59 07   #...0......s^.Y.
05d0 - 02 1a eb 7e b8 23 0f f3-f5 8a 95 e3 a6 a1 6d a4   ...~.#........m.
05e0 - 6b 30 69 31 0b 30 09 06-03 55 04 06 13 02 44 45   k0i1.0...U....DE
05f0 - 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04-08 13 03 4e 52 57 31 0e   1.0...U....NRW1.
0600 - 30 0c 06 03 55 04 07 13-05 4b 6f 65 6c 6e 31 11   0...U....Koeln1.
0610 - 30 0f 06 03 55 04 0a 13-08 46 48 20 4b 6f 65 6c   0...U....FH Koel
0620 - 6e 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55-04 0b 13 03 4c 41 62 31   n1.0...U....LAb1
0630 - 1b 30 19 06 03 55 04 03-13 12 54 72 75 73 74 20   .0...U....Trust 
0640 - 43 65 6e 74 65 72 20 49-68 73 61 6e 82 09 00 f1   Center Ihsan....
0650 - d1 e7 03 e4 b3 7c 32 30-0c 06 03 55 1d 13 04 05   .....|20...U....
0660 - 30 03 01 01 ff 30 0d 06-09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01   0....0...*.H....
0670 - 01 05 05 00 03 82 01 01-00 b7 df 61 14 5d 57 17   ...........a.]W.
0680 - 3c c0 2c fe 37 df c2 24-ce ea 61 6b 84 d2 fa f3   <.,.7..$..ak....
0690 - 6a cd 79 f1 71 08 f6 8c-bf ed d6 60 38 d2 35 62   j.y.q......`8.5b
06a0 - 23 5b 3f 9e 23 32 61 b4-fb a3 3d f5 df 14 ca 59   #[?.#2a...=....Y
06b0 - 50 37 fc d3 0c bb 13 b2-0d 1c 1f b4 9b 6b 6f b2   P7...........ko.
06c0 - b6 9d c9 d3 d6 a4 f1 7e-07 aa 52 47 39 a9 7a a3   .......~..RG9.z.
06d0 - b4 1c ba 88 c2 f6 27 e8-b4 49 55 62 7c 92 23 6b   ......'..IUb|.#k
06e0 - 4b 70 a7 52 db 9e 3a aa-e6 d3 d7 53 0f f4 e0 60   Kp.R..:....S...`
06f0 - ae ee f9 ce 69 23 d0 66-c6 a5 9e 2f 79 ae fd e2   ....i#.f.../y...
0700 - 62 41 bf c8 66 15 40 6e-1a 81 52 4e 50 1d 57 b9   bA..f.@n..RNP.W.
0710 - b9 03 dc 26 bf 04 47 94-30 26 38 72 e8 6d 50 eb   ...&..G.0&8r.mP.
0720 - 87 ca 31 55 1e dc 1e dc-11 ad 19 af 0e 83 18 1c   ..1U............
0730 - b5 5d 92 d4 2d 52 e9 9a-04 95 f4 c7 d6 fc 15 8f   .]..-R..........
0740 - 37 47 eb 8d 70 b6 3b f2-36 cb 04 08 f7 fb 31 fc   7G..p.;.6.....1.
0750 - 3a c9 e6 d6 4c 57 b9 32-7c 8d bf 7e 92 7c f1 95   :...LW.2|..~.|..
0760 - 1c 09 22 f9 14 a1 f5 e3-71 d2 22 38 72 e4 2d 0d   ..".....q."8r.-.
0770 - 77 a0 11 fa 9c fa 20 0b-97                        w..... ..
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write certificate A
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 00cd]
    0c 00 00 c9 03 00 17 41 04 3e 04 b1 f7 2c 1c b2
    e1 c7 17 7e 50 64 4b b9 d5 c8 fc bb 31 d6 44 a7
    01 cb ad fa cc fa ef 14 82 90 69 28 a9 96 39 54
    9a 1b 49 6b 0b cd b6 55 9a 85 b6 4a 40 1f aa cd
    6a 0c 8c cd 3f 24 32 bc b6 06 01 00 80 77 86 c4
    74 e3 cd 58 62 52 d9 ae 55 1b ee 61 33 24 a6 0f
    7b 78 86 3f 45 7b 2f 5a 77 95 f8 0b fa 63 a0 64
    d3 aa 31 eb 41 76 a1 04 c8 38 26 67 f7 56 33 e6
    c6 21 91 e2 27 25 1d dc 15 74 54 6d 5e cc b2 04
    f6 f1 90 d6 ea 24 a6 b4 78 fc 50 f8 46 05 92 11
    31 62 5c e6 06 b9 d8 2f 83 aa 26 3b 5d c9 8f 54
    9a 02 55 33 13 4f dc b9 9b 4e 3c 0b 5c 13 65 b9
    f4 f7 4a a2 90 63 42 fa a7 36 8b ab 5a
write to 0x147cb40 [0x14902c0] (210 bytes => 210 (0xD2))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 cd 0c 00 00-c9 03 00 17 41 04 3e 04   ............A.>.
0010 - b1 f7 2c 1c b2 e1 c7 17-7e 50 64 4b b9 d5 c8 fc   ..,.....~PdK....
0020 - bb 31 d6 44 a7 01 cb ad-fa cc fa ef 14 82 90 69   .1.D...........i
0030 - 28 a9 96 39 54 9a 1b 49-6b 0b cd b6 55 9a 85 b6   (..9T..Ik...U...
0040 - 4a 40 1f aa cd 6a 0c 8c-cd 3f 24 32 bc b6 06 01   J@...j...?$2....
0050 - 00 80 77 86 c4 74 e3 cd-58 62 52 d9 ae 55 1b ee   ..w..t..XbR..U..
0060 - 61 33 24 a6 0f 7b 78 86-3f 45 7b 2f 5a 77 95 f8   a3$..{x.?E{/Zw..
0070 - 0b fa 63 a0 64 d3 aa 31-eb 41 76 a1 04 c8 38 26   ..c.d..1.Av...8&
0080 - 67 f7 56 33 e6 c6 21 91-e2 27 25 1d dc 15 74 54   g.V3..!..'%...tT
0090 - 6d 5e cc b2 04 f6 f1 90-d6 ea 24 a6 b4 78 fc 50   m^........$..x.P
00a0 - f8 46 05 92 11 31 62 5c-e6 06 b9 d8 2f 83 aa 26   .F...1b\..../..&
00b0 - 3b 5d c9 8f 54 9a 02 55-33 13 4f dc b9 9b 4e 3c   ;]..T..U3.O...N<
00c0 - 0b 5c 13 65 b9 f4 f7 4a-a2 90 63 42 fa a7 36 8b   .\.e...J..cB..6.
00d0 - ab 5a                                             .Z
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write key exchange A
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 0004]
    0e 00 00 00
write to 0x147cb40 [0x14902c0] (9 bytes => 9 (0x9))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 04 0e                                 ......
0009 - <SPACES/NULS>
SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A
SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
read from 0x147cb40 [0x14868a3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02                                    .....
read from 0x147cb40 [0x14868a8] (2 bytes => 2 (0x2))
0000 - 02 50                                             .P
<<< TLS 1.2  [length 0002]
    02 50
SSL3 alert read:fatal:internal error
SSL_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
ERROR
140298234844832:error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error:s3_pkt.c:1256:SSL alert number 80
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

I am new in Java and SSL programming in Ubuntu. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TLSv1.2 does not seem to be available when you call SSLContext.getInstance().

This depends on the type and version of Java you are using, what cryptography providers you use and how you start java, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html .

Starting java with -server should turn TLSv1.2 on.